# Why does Apache CloseableHttpResponse not consume the entity on close?

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x, autocloseable

Looking at the [quick start guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html) it gives the following code example:

```java
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://targethost/homepage");
CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
// The underlying HTTP connection is still held by the response object
// to allow the response content to be streamed directly from the network socket.
// In order to ensure correct deallocation of system resources
// the user MUST call CloseableHttpResponse#close() from a finally clause.
// Please note that if response content is not fully consumed the underlying
// connection cannot be safely re-used and will be shut down and discarded
// by the connection manager. 
try {
    System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine());
    HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
    // do something useful with the response body
    // and ensure it is fully consumed
    EntityUtils.consume(entity1);
} finally {
    response1.close();
}
```

The two comments in the code above say that we must close the response object for

> "correct deallocation of system resources"

and

> "if response content is not fully consumed the underlying connection cannot be safely re-used and will be shut down and discarded by the connection manager".

Now Apache have very kindly implementend a CloseableHttpResponse for us, which means we can use a try-with-resources block. But the close method only closes the response object, why doesn't it also consume the entity?

Comment: You just asked my exact question with exact words. this is y we have stackoverflow to read multiple developers mind, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Because it is hard to say at that point whether or not the caller intends to re-use the underlying connection. In some cases one may want to read just a small chunk from a large response body and immediately terminate the connection.

In other words, the same thing happens over and over again: there is no one way that can make everyone happy.

The code snippet will do ensure proper de-allocation of resources while trying to keep the underlying connection alive.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://targethost/homepage");
CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
try {
    System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine());
} finally {
    EntityUtils.consume(response1.getEntity());
}
```