# Right way to close CloseableHttpResponse/CloseableHttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, resource-cleanup, autocloseable

I'm using CloseableHttpResponse (from apache-httpclient-4.5.3) and I'm not sure I'm using it right, I saw an [answer with no votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44469833/why-does-apache-closeablehttpresponse-not-consume-the-entity-on-close) to use `EntityUtils.consume` on finally:

> ```
> CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
>
> try {
>
>  System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine());
>
> } finally {
>
>  EntityUtils.consume(response1.getEntity());
> ```

`CloseableHttpClient` is abstract and has no close method to call although in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574478/what-is-the-difference-between-closeablehttpclient-and-httpclient-in-apache-http) it's used:

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
try {
    //do something
} finally {
    response.close();
}
```

Currently I'm using try with resources for `CloseableHttpClient` and `CloseableHttpResponse` inside of send method.

Am I not missing any resource open or using it in a wrong way?

```
private CloseableHttpResponse send()
            throws URISyntaxException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException, ClientProtocolException {
        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(BASE_URL);
        HttpHost target = new HttpHost(uriBuilder.getHost(), uriBuilder.getPort(), uriBuilder.getScheme());
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uriBuilder.build());
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().build(); CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(target, post)) {            
            return response;
        }
```

Comment: Just a note: CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet), the execute method is deprecated on version 5.2.1.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It has been explained in detail in the docs [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/quickstart.html).
Quoting the pseudo code from the docs here's a typical way to allocate/deallocate an instance of `CloseableHttpClient`:

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
    <...>
}
```

The same applies to `CloseableHttpResponse` :

```
try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget)) {
    <...>
}
```

Now, about the close method in `CloseableHttpClient`. `CloseableHttpClient` is an abstract class that implements `Closeable` interface. That is, although it doesn't have a `close` method itself the classes that extend it are required to implement the `close` method. One class is `InternalHttpClient`. You can check the source code for the details.

Before Java7, explicit close would be required:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
try {
    <...>
} finally {
    httpclient.close();
}

CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
try {
    <...>
} finally {
    response.close();
}
```

Comment: My method with `try with resources` is equally acceptable?

Comment: Yes. There are several ways to deallocated `Closeable` resources, one of which would be try-with-resources. It depends on your use case how and when to close your resources, however.

Comment: In this case I just create request and execute it. it seems right way to use `try with resources`

Comment: there's no need for `EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity())`?

Comment: @user7294900 There is, in case you are not sure whether or not your code always consumes the entire response message content. And try-with-resources is the right way but it does not negate the basic principle outlined by atoMerz

Comment: @oleg This is my code, and I can't use `response` in finally if it's inside `try with resources`

Comment: @user7294900 so what? The response gets closed implicitly by the runtime

Comment: And yet they say here that is threadsafe and recommend that one instance be used for multiple requests?  https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e213

Comment: @slashdottir It seems to me this is a new question posted as a comment. I'd recommend posting a new question and explaining in more detail what it is you're looking for. It is not clear to me as of now what you're asking.

Answer (score 8):

You can avoid the finally by using the try(resource)

> try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet)) {
>   ... }